# Report percentage of failure on GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I use Cloud Functions (CF) at Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I have a queue that sends messages to multiple cloud functions every day. For example, one day spawning 1000 CF and the next day 5548 CF! In my monitoring, I would like to know the percentage of failure. For example, considering my two-day example, if 100 CF fails on the first day and 225 on the second day, my percentage of failure would be (100+225)/(1000+5548).

Then I could monitor this percentage and do reporting on it. How can I achieve this in GCP? Does GCP Monitoring provide such an option built-in?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Cloud Monitoring.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks! can you elaborate? Any documentation page or option/feature name you could direct me to? I can see the 'rate' option but that does not do what I want (I can't find anything for rate of failure)